# Don't include bbCode in reading time and word/character counters

Tags: php, count, bbcode

I use different functions in PHP that helps me to count words, characters, and also the reading time. But they have all one slight "error": the functions counts everything - including the bbCode (with smileys). I don't want that!

```
function calculate_readingtime($string) {
    $word = str_word_count(strip_tags($string));
    $m = floor($word / 200);
    $s = floor($word % 200 / (200 / 60));

    $minutes = ($m != 0 ? $m.' min.' : '');
    $seconds = (($m != 0 AND $s != 0) ? ' ' : '') . $s.' sec.';

    return $minutes . $seconds;
}

$content = 'This is some text with [b]bbCode[/b]! Oh, so pretty :D And here\'s is a link too: [url="https://example.com/"]das linkish[/url]. What about an image? That\'s pretty to, you know. [img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" size="128" height="128" width="128"] And another one: [img src="https://example.com/image.jpg" height="128"]';
$reading_time = calculate_readingtime($content);
$count_words = str_word_count($content, 1, 'àáãâçêéíîóõôúÀÁÃÂÇÊÉÍÎÓÕÔÚÅåÄäÖö');
$count_chars_with_spaces = mb_strlen($content);

echo 'Reading time: '.$reading_time.'<br>';
echo 'Words: '.count($count_words).'<br>';
echo 'Characters with spaces: '.$count_chars_with_spaces;

# OUTPUT
Reading time: 16 sec.
Words: 55
Characters with spaces: 326
```

I want the counters (including the reading time) to be more accurate and don't include the bbCode but include the text that are within the bbCode (example: include the text `bbCode` from `[b]bbCode[/b]`).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually relatively easy to parse BBCode out of a string using [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), especially in languages like PHP that support the PCRE library. Assuming a few things about your BBCode syntax, here's the shortest way:

```
preg_replace('@\[(?:\w+(?:="(?>.*?"))?(?: \w+="(?>.*?"))*|/\w+)]@s', '', $content);
```

[Demo on Regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/0vN638/1)

Or a better way that's more precise with end tags and nesting:

```
function parse($str) {
    return preg_replace_callback('@\[(\w+)(?:="(?>.*?"))?(?: \w+="(?>.*?"))*](?:(.*?)\[/\1])?@s',
        function($matches) { return $matches[2] ? parse($matches[2]) : ''; },
        $str
    );
}
```

[Demo on Ideone](http://ideone.com/YSgZx4)